# Use STL string with unicode

Tags: string, unicode

I am coding a plugin for autodesk 3dsmax and they recommend to use the _T(x) macro for every string literal to make it work with unicode as well. I am using the stl string class a lot in this code. So do I have to rewrite the code: string("foo") to: string(_T("foo")) ? Actually the stl string class doesnt have a constructor for wchars, so it doesnt make sense, does it?

Thx

Comment: I don't think std::string is depending on any encoding. You can store unicode encoded strings in there, but the member functions might return funny results :) It depends on what you're doing with the strings.

Comment: Using these macros stopped making sense quite a while ago.  Use std::wstring in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the definition of "T" macro - it expands to "L" in "Unicode" builds or nothing in "non-Unicode" builds. If you want to keep using the string calss and follow the recommendation for your plugin, your best bet is to use something like [tstring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188714.aspx) which would follow the same rules.

But the truth is - all this "T" business made a lot of sense 10 years ago - all modern Windows versions are Unicode-only and you can just use wstring.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an own string class say `xstring` and use the _T for constants and then internally, depending on unicode or not switch to `string` or `wstring`. either that or instantiate `xstring<yourchartype>`